# RAILS - How do I add a select tag and put all my category items

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have a scaffold for both blogs and post_category.

I made an association with both of them. Here's my schema:

```
  create_table "blogs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "body"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "slug"
    t.integer "status", default: 0
    t.bigint "post_category_id"
    t.index ["post_category_id"], name: "index_blogs_on_post_category_id"
    t.index ["slug"], name: "index_blogs_on_slug", unique: true
  end

  create_table "post_categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.text "description"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

So simply I created a couple of post categories and when I try to make an association with blog items so whenever I create a new blog I can display a select statement and choose my preferred category for the blog item I am trying to create but I don't know how to display all categories on all forms and on the index.html.erb file:

```
  <div class="field">
  <%= form.label :category %>
  <%= form.collection_select :post_category, PostCategory.all %>
  </div>
```

How can I achieve this? And make sure that it saves the data as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per [this reference](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select), the format is

```
collection_select(object, method, collection, value_method, text_method, options = {}, html_options = {})
```

and for your code, it can be like this

```
<%= form.collection_select(:post_category, :post_category_id, PostCategory.all, :id, :name, prompt: true) %>
```

update 2:

inside your blog_controllers

```
# white list parameter 
  def blog_params
    params.require(:blog).permit(
      :post_category_id,
      ... others fields
    )
  end
```

Comment: Upon saving the form I am havint this error: 1 error prohibited this blog from being saved:
Post category must exist

Comment: you can add couple of content, open your terminal, run rails console and type this  PostCategory.create(name: "Cat 1", description: "Cat 1")

Comment: <div class="field">
  <%= form.label :category %>
  <%= form.collection_select(:post_category_id, PostCategory.all, :id, :name)%>
  </div>

Comment: This one works but when I check on the rails console it doesn't save the data.

Comment: make sure you have white list post_category_id inside your controller (see my update number 2 above)

Comment: Just one last question i have in mind on the index.html.erb file I want to display the name of the category but this code doesnt work:   `<td><%= blog.post_category_id.name %></td>` Any idea?

Comment: sure just pust the name of the parent like this (without _id) <td><%= blog.post_category.name %></td>

Comment: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Comment: `<td><%= PostCategory.all.each do |c|
           c.name if c.id == blog.post_category
          %></td>` I tried this but also doesnt work,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186024/discussion-between-widjajayd-and-marc-solva).